# Issues With Angular ngRoute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have spent hours and hours searching and googling to find out why my ngRoute is not working but couldn't find the solution so i decided to come here. Here is my code::

"app.js"

```
angular.module("sandwichApp",["cart", "ngRoute"])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
    .
    when("/",{
        templateUrl: "app/views/sandwichList.html",
        controller: "SandwichListController"
    }).
    when("/sandwichList",{
        templateUrl: "app/views/sandwichList.html"
    }).    
    when("/checkout",{
        templateUrl: "app/views/cart.html"
    }).    
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/app/views/sandwichList.html"

    });
}]);
// for this particular code i have tried the version where the config() doesn't contain array "[]" but only the function and it also doesn't work


"sandwichListController.js"
var main = angular.module("sandwichApp", ["clientAppServiceModule"]);
main.controller("SandwichListController", function($scope, ClientAppService, cart){

    $scope.original = {
        sandwiches : []
    }

//.... more code here. THERE IS NO PROBLEM WITH THIS CONTROLLER SO THE CODE IS NOT IMPORTANT.
);
```

"index.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sandwichApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>
      <!--script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script-->
      <script src="app.js"></script>
      <script src="app/services/clientAppService.js"></script>
      <script src="app/controllers/sandwichListController.js"></script>
      <script src="app/model/cart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="SandwichListController">

      <div><strong>Heading & Cart</strong></div>

<div ng-view></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

"sandwichList.html"

```
<div>
   <b>Your Cart: </b> 
    {{totalItems}} items / {{totPrice | currency}}
   <span><a href="/checkout">checkout</a></span>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="sandwichName"  ng-change="filterSandwich()"/>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>Sandwiches </h1>
</div>

  <div ng-repeat="sandwich in workingCopy.sandwiches">
      <h3 ng-click="addItemToCart(sandwich)">
          <strong>{{sandwich.Name}}</strong>
          <span>{{sandwich.Price | currency}}</span>
      </h3>
 </div>
```

When i load the "index.html" page, i expect the "otherwise" section of the routeer to display the "sandwichList.html" in the `<div ng-view></div>` section but it doesn't work. If it can't find the file, it will complain but it doesn't complain meaning that the file is at the right location. Yet it does not work.

In the sandwichList page at least if the controllers will not work, it must be able to display the `<h1>Sandwiches </h1>` .

My chrome console doesn't display any errors so i don't know what is causing the problem

Comment: I'm sure you're doing this, but you need to use a web server with ng-route.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be because you are accidentally declaring your app twice. When registering a new module in angular you provide it a second parameter which is an array of dependencies. You are doing that where you specify your routes. However, when you go to create your controller, you're code is this:

```
var main = angular.module("sandwichApp", ["clientAppServiceModule"]);
```

Angular sees the dependencies and assumes it is to create a new app. When it realizes there is already one with the same name, it overwrites it and you lose all the route stuff you setup. Try passing your "clientAppServiceModule" to the initial app definition, then just creating your controller by doing this:

```
angular.module("sandwichApp").controller("SandwichListController", function($scope, ClientAppService, cart){

    $scope.original = {
        sandwiches : []
    }

//.... more code here. THERE IS NO PROBLEM WITH THIS CONTROLLER SO THE CODE IS NOT IMPORTANT.
);
```

Let me know if you have any questions, or if that doesn't solve it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i have moved the "clientAppServiceModule" into the module array [] of the app.js file. Now i get this error in the console "angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=sandwichApp&p1=Erro…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A381) "

Comment: you'll need to include your clientAppService.js file before your app.js file since you are injecting it into the main app now.

Comment: i have moved clientAppService.js above app.js but the same error

Comment: you are also passing a "cart" dependency which appears to be included below the app definition

Comment: After making the changes, i get this error:: " angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=sandwichApp&p1=Erro…0%20%20at%20c%20(http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A54142%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A19)  "

Comment: SO is screwing up that link so I'm not getting the full detail. Would you be able to update your code in the original post so I can see the current state of things? Thanks!